# What does the C standard say about pointers to structs and their first member?

Tags: c, struct, pointers, standards

Consider the following two `struct`:

```
struct a
{
    int a;
};

struct b
{
    struct a a_struct;
    int b;
};
```

the following instantiation of `struct b`:

```
struct b b_struct;
```

and this condition:

```
if (&b_struct == (struct b*)&b_struct.a_struct)
    printf("Yes\n");
```

Does the C standard mandate this to always evaluate true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, according to 6.7.2.1, "Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning."

Comment: I dislike the wording 'suitably converted'. It gives the impression this relationship could be broken by casts (or lack of).

Comment: @James: The wording is there simply due to the type differences that must exist between a pointer to a struct and a pointer to the first member of the struct.

Answer (score 5):

Can't find it in the C Standard, but the answer is "yes" - the C++ Standard says:

> A pointer to a POD-struct object,
>   suitably converted using a
>   reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which
>   it resides) and vice versa. [Note:
>   There might therefore be unnamed
>   padding within a POD-struct object,
>   but not at its beginning, as necessary
>   to achieve appropriate alignment. ]

As C and C++ POD objects must be compatible, the same must be true for C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There must not be any padding in front of the first member.

The address of a structure is the same as the address of its first member, provided that the appropriate cast is used.

[resource](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html)